# Why JComboBox firing toString() on mouse hover?

Tags: java, swing

I have created a simple GUI, one JComboBox and JButton.
JButton populate the JComboBox with objects of class testString.
When mouse hover the JComboBox it fired toString() of testString class almost 25 time.  Why this happening? How we can stop it?

here is code:

```
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;

public class _NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public _NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    
    Object[] args = {new testString("ABC") , new testString("EDF") , "GIH", "IJK"}; 
    jComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(args ));
}                                        
public static void main(String args[]) {
        

            new _NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            
             
}

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
}



class testString {
String text; 
static int i; 
testString(String text){ this.text = text; }; 


public String toString(){
    System.out.println("ToSting() Called on Text " + text + " "+ ++i);

    return text; 
}


}
```

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0xZb.jpg)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRO2s.jpg)

Comment: maybe if you showed the relevant code, we might know

Comment: The default cell renderer used by `JComboBox` (`DefaultListCellRenderer`) use `Object#toString` to set the text which is displayed.  Because the combobox also uses the result of the `ListCellRenderer` to calculate it's `preferredSize`, the `toString` method may be called multiple times even before it's displayed

Comment: An alternative, if you don't want to provide a custom renderer, you can also just wrap your Objects in a new wrapper class, do the "toString" computation once, keep a reference to the result and just return the result in the wrapper's toString() method. In that way, no matter how many times it is called, the string creation code will be executed only once for each item. You could also do it lazily, but no point in this case, since it seems that toString() is called right away anyway.

Comment: After adding the missing code, your console output only happened when you selected a text value in the `JComboBox`, not when just hovering over the `JComboBox` with the mouse.  The `toString` method should simply return a text representation of an instance of your class, and not do any additional processing.  Then it doesn't matter if it's called 100 times or more.

Answer (score 2):

You can't stop the `JComboBox` from calling the `toString()` method of your items.

This is because the `JComboBox` needs to know what text it has to show to the user.

For this it calls the `toString()` method of the items (of the currently shown item on mouse-over, of all items when the drop down list).

---

Well, you can sort of stop it by [providing a custom renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) - a class that implements the `javax.swing.ListCellRenderer` interface.

It is the default `ListCellRenderer` that effectively calls the `toString()` method on your items. If you provide a custom `ListCellRenderer` implementation it can call any other method of your liking.

But expect as many calls to the `ListCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent()` method as you see calls to your items `toString()` method.